# Incorrect placement of token in 2D grid

Tags: python, grid, token

I'm making a treasure hunt game on a changeable 8 x 8, 10 x 10 or 12 x 12 grid as part of an assignment for school and I need some help. Whenever I make the move on  the grid it doesn't always move to the desired position. Can someone help me or explain to me why it doesn't work?

The code below is what I have so far.

```
def makeMove():
   global board, numberOfMoves, tokenBoard, playerScore, tokenBoard
   playerCoords = getPlayerPosition()
   currentRow = playerCoords[0] #sets var to playerCoords[0]
   currentCol = playerCoords[1] #sets var to playerCoords[1]

   directionUD = input("Up/Down?") #sets var to the input of "Up/down?"
   movement_col = int(input("How many places?"))
   if directionUD == "u": #checks if var equals "u"
      newCol = currentCol - movement_col
      print (newCol)
   elif directionUD =="d": #checks if var equals "d"
      newCol = currentCol + movement_col

   directionLR = input("Left/Right?") #sets var to the input of "Up/down?"
   movement_row = int(input("How many places?"))
   if directionLR == "l": #checks if var equals "l"
     newRow = currentRow - movement_row
     print(newRow)
  elif directionLR == "r": #checks if var equals "r"
     newRow = currentRow + movement_row
     print(newRow)

  calculatePoints(newCol, newRow) #calls the calculatePoints function

  if newCol > gridSize or newRow > gridSize:
    print("That move will place you outside of the grid. Please try again.")


   board[newCol][newRow] = "X" #sets the new position to "X"
   board[currentRow][currentCol] = "-"
   numberOfMoves = numberOfMoves + 1 #adds 1 to the numberOfMoves
   displayBoard() #calls the displayBoard function
```

Comment: From just visually inspecting your current code, nothing jumps out as being obviously wrong (there's room for improvement but nothing seems to result in unexpected behaviour). Can you include the code or `calculatePoints` and elaborate on ` it doesn't always move to the desired position`?

Comment: Your comment `#sets var to the input of "Up/down?"` is duplicated by the way. The second time is for "Left/Right".

Comment: Also your condition `if newCol > gridSize or newRow > gridSize:` should use `>=` shouldn't it? It should also return or raise an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I feel like an idiot. It took reproducing your work from scratch before I noticed the problem - I'm confusing *columns* with *rows*. I think this might be your issue as well.

In your game, you should determine your player's *horizontal* movement ('Left/Right?') by changing the current *column* and the player's *vertical* movement ('Up/Down?') by changing the current *row*.

This is because when you determine a value for `newRow` that differs from `currentRow`, you're moving *across* rows rather than *along* them. Similar logic applies for columns.

Here's my code below for reference:

```
def create_board(size):
    return [['_' for _ in range(size)] for _ in range(size)]


def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print(row)


def get_board_dimensions(board):
    # PRE: board has at least one row and column
    return len(board), len(board[0])


def make_move(board, player_position):
    def query_user_for_movement():
        while True:
            try:
                return int(input('How many places? '))
            except ValueError:
                continue

    def query_user_for_direction(query, *valid_directions):
        while True:
            direction = input(query)
            if direction in valid_directions:
                return direction

    vertical_direction = query_user_for_direction('Up/Down? ', 'u', 'd')
    vertical_displacement = query_user_for_movement()
    horizontal_direction = query_user_for_direction('Left/Right? ', 'l', 'r')
    horizontal_displacement = query_user_for_movement()

    curr_row, curr_column = player_position
    new_row = curr_row + vertical_displacement * (1 if vertical_direction == 'd' else -1)
    new_column = curr_column + horizontal_displacement * (1 if horizontal_direction == 'r' else -1)

    width, height = get_board_dimensions(board)

    if not (0 <= new_row < height):
        raise ValueError('Cannot move to row {} on board with height {}'.format(new_row, height))
    elif not (0 <= new_column < width):
        raise ValueError('Cannot move to column {} on board with width {}'.format(new_column, width))

    board[curr_row][curr_column] = '_'
    board[new_row][new_column] = 'X'

    return board


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Set up an 8 x 8 board with the player at a specific location
    board_size = 8
    player_position = (1, 2)
    board = create_board(board_size)
    board[player_position[0]][player_position[1]] = 'X'
    print('Initialised board with size {} and player at ({}, {})'.format(board_size, *player_position))
    print_board(board)

    # Allow the player to make their move.
    print('Player, make your move:\n')
    board = make_move(board, player_position)

    # Show the new board state
    print('Board after making move')
    print_board(board)
```

**Starting a game**

```
Initialised board with size 8 and player at (1, 2)
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['_', '_', 'X', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
Player, make your move:
```

**Moving one tile down**

```
Up/Down? d
How many places? 1
Left/Right? r
How many places? 0
Board after making move
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['_', '_', 'X', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
```

**Moving one tile right**

```
Up/Down? d
How many places? 0
Left/Right? r
How many places? 1
Board after making move
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['_', '_', '_', 'X', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
```

**Moving one tile up**

```
Up/Down? u
How many places? 1
Left/Right? l
How many places? 0
Board after making move
['_', '_', 'X', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
```

**Moving one tile left**

```
Up/Down? d
How many places? 0
Left/Right? l
How many places? 1
Board after making move
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['_', 'X', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
```

**Moving diagonally down and right**

```
Up/Down? d
How many places? 1
Left/Right? r
How many places? 1
Board after making move
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['_', '_', '_', 'X', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
```

**Making an illegal move**

```
Up/Down? u
How many places? 3
Left/Right? r
How many places? 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/<<me>>/.PyCharmCE2016.3/config/scratches/scratch_2.py", line 62, in <module>
    board = make_move(board, player_position)
  File "C:/Users/<<me>>/.PyCharmCE2016.3/config/scratches/scratch_2.py", line 41, in make_move
    raise ValueError('Cannot move to row {} on board with height {}'.format(new_row, height))
ValueError: Cannot move to row -2 on board with height 8
```